# Combine Einsum Expressions

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I would like to evaluate

```
E = np.einsum('ij,jk,kl->ijkl',A,A,A)
F = np.einsum('ijki->ijk',E)
```

where A is a matrix (no more than 1000 by 1000 in size). Computing E is slow. I would like to speed this up by only computing the "diagonal" elements which I store in F. Is it possible to combine these two expressions?/Are there any better ways to speed up this computation?

Comment: How would you define "diagonal" elements in a `3D` array like `F`? Add a sample case?

Comment: The diagonal elements are those that I extract and store in F.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is an automatic way, but you can always do the maths yourself and give `einsum` the final expression:

```
F = np.einsum('ij,jk,ki->ijk', A, A, A)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [86]: A=np.random.randint(0,100,(100,100))

In [88]: E1=np.einsum('ijki->ijk',np.einsum('ij,jk,kl->ijkl',A,A,A))

In [89]: E2=np.einsum('ij,jk,ki->ijk',A,A,A)

In [90]: np.allclose(E1,E2)
Out[90]: True
```

Good time improvement - 100x, corresponding to the saved dimension (`l`)

```
In [91]: timeit np.einsum('ijki->ijk',np.einsum('ij,jk,kl->ijkl',A,A,A))
1 loops, best of 3: 1.1 s per loop

In [92]: timeit np.einsum('ij,jk,ki->ijk',A,A,A)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop
```

`einsum` performs a combined iteration over all the indices, albeit in Cython code.  So reducing the number of indices can have a significant time savings.  Looks like doing that `i...i` combination works in the initial calc.

With only 2g of memory, the (1000,1000) is too large  'iterator too large' in the E1 case, 'memory error' in the E2 case.

Comment: Thanks! This really helps. Is there any way to deal with the "iterator too large problem"? My final goal is to compute                                                  G = np.einsum('ij,jk,kl,lm,mi->ijklm',A,A,A,A,A) with A being a 500 x 500 matrix of 1's and 0's.

Comment: Your `G` matrix would have `500**5` items, which is roughly 31 **trillion**. Even if you only needed 1 byte per item, you are looking at 30 TB of RAM. So you may want to rethink what you want to do...

Comment: You are right about 'good old C'.  I must have been thinking of the bit of Cython sum-of-products I wrote when working out a patch. :)